Maximum value of $\displaystyle f(x)=\bigg|\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+2a^2}-\sqrt{2a^2-3-\cos^2(x)}\bigg|$

Maximum value of

$\displaystyle f(x)=\bigg|\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+2a^2}-\sqrt{2a^2-3-\cos^2(x)}\bigg|$
What I try : Put $\displaystyle 2a^2-\cos^2(x)=t$
So we have  $\displaystyle f(t)=\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt{t-3}$
$\displaystyle f'(t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+t}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t-3}}<0$ for $t\geq 3$
So we get $\displaystyle f(t)$ is maximum when $t=3$
So we get maximum of $f(t)$ is $2$
Can we solve it without using derivative, If yes please explain me , Thanks

$\sqrt a - \sqrt b = \frac{a-b}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b}$

It seems that the maximum value of $f(x)$ is not always $2$. According to WolframAlpha, for $a=2$, the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $2\sqrt 2-2$. Your question may not be so simple.

First of all, we have to have $2a^2-3-\cos^2(x)\ge 0$, so $2a^2-3\ge \cos^2(x)\ge 0$. So, it is necessary that $2a^2-3\ge 0$.
Let $t:=2a^2-\cos^2(x)$ as you did.
Using $\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$ which hellofriends commented, we have
$$f(x)=\bigg|\frac{4}{\sqrt{t+1}+\sqrt{t-3}}\bigg|=\frac{4}{\sqrt{t+1}+\sqrt{t-3}}:=g(t)$$
which is strictly decreasing.
Here, since $0\leq \cos^2(x)\leq 1$, we have to have $$t+1\geq 0\quad\text{and}\quad t-3\geq 0\quad\text{and}\quad 0\leq 2a^2-t\leq 1$$
i.e.
$$\max(3,2a^2-1)\leq t\leq 2a^2$$
Now, let us separate it into two cases :
Case 1 : If $3\lt 2a^2-1$, then the maximum value of $g(t)$ is $g(2a^2-1)=\sqrt{2a^2}-\sqrt{2a^2-4}$.
Case 2 : If $3\geq 2a^2-1$ and $2a^2-3\ge 0$, then the maximum value of $g(t)$ is $g(3)=2$.
In conclusion, the maximum value of $f(x)$ is
$$\color{red}{\begin{cases}\sqrt{2a^2}-\sqrt{2a^2-4}&\text{if $|a|\gt \sqrt 2$}
\\\\2&\text{if $\frac{\sqrt 6}{2}\leq |a|\leq \sqrt 2$}\end{cases}}$$
